# Save to EEPROM at power down using STM32

Tags: stm32, eeprom

I am using STM32F030R8. I have enabled a counter that counts value at fixed interval. I was wondering whether i can save this counter value to eeprom as soon as i switch off the power to the uController. I am using 24C08 i2c eeprom. I can use large bulk capacitor say 1000uF or any suggested value ..

Comment: Search for PVD in your Reference manual

Comment: Great help for pointing me out. This will do the work but i am not able to call functions from the releted c files. I did try to import the header file but in vain... Any more guidance please ?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of reading i have finally found that PVD is not supported in STM32F030R8 ... I need to look for another alternative method.

Thanks.

Comment: It was enough to browse the RM. Easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

If  no PDV  use ADC in the watchdog mode.

[image]